# Event participants import

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civicrm-home, participants

I'm building a new database on for my organization because of some issues and too many duplicates. I transferred all my contact, relations, contributions. Now I created new events and I'm trying to import the participants into the database but there is nothing that I can match it to a contact that is already on my database, it doesn't give me the option to match to contact ID or email (see attached image). Is there an extension or any other way I can override and import the participants?
[image]

Comment: Hi Ali. https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui may give you more options

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thank you. But it didn't help, it gave me some extra options, but it didn't give me the options that I needed to match an email or contact ID to a record.

Comment: In your import settings does it offer eg Update or Fill or Skip?  Wondering if you don't see Internal ID if eg you have Update selected (think similar happens in Contacts)